# How to repeat an image while you are scrolling?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i repeat an image on background? I'm trying to put an image (a notebook sheet) into a scrollview. But i can't figure out how to make it. Can you give me an example?
I'm new at android programming.

PD:Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i unterstand you correctly, This way help you.

Import a drawable image like that "img_blue_gray.png"

Then create a xml file in **Drawable Folder**

> **repeating.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:src="@drawable/img_blue_gray"
      android:tileMode="repeat"
/>
```

> For example: usage in Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parrent"
    android:layout_height="match_parrent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
         android:layout_width="match_parrent"
         android:layout_height="match_parrent"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:background="@drawable/repeating.xml">

         /* Your other views */

   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```